# Access variables like a text?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, variables, dynamic

Let's say i got a variable Var123;

```
var x = "Var";

var VariableMixLOL = x + "123";
//so VariableMixLOL should be equal to Var123, ex. Var123 = "Abc", VariableMixLOL should be "Abc" too
```

How can I do this? Btw i'm using as3

PS: Added at Tags JS too because i think it's the same thing

Comment: I don't think this question is very clear. What's not working? What's the expected output?

Comment: Well, in JS you can't, you need to create an object to do that. like `var variable = {Var123 : 'hello'}; var x= 'Var'; var VariableMixLOL = variable[x+'123'];`

Comment: It's not the same thing.

Comment: Anyway, I edited it.. for the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
var x = "Var";
var Var123 = "lalaala";
var VariableMixLOL = eval( x + "123" );
```

Another option and the better one is to model such things in a JavascriptObject.

```
var x = "variable";
var variables = { "variable123" : "laalala"}; //OR variables = {}; variables["variable123"] = "laalala";

var VariableMixLOL = variables[ x + "123"];
```

Comment: try it yourself please (i dont have as3), the second solution should be written again correctly if you plan to use that.

Comment: btw, why don't you write variables = "lalalal" at 2nd row? Isn't it the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Variable name as String can be used if you incorporate an object to which you store it.

For example:

```
var x = "Var";
var compoundVar = x + "123";
var obj : Object = {};
obj[compoundVar] = 7;

//Now you can call the variable like this
trace(obj.Var123); //7
```

Comment: But I also like `sabithpocker`'s answer a lot!

Comment: Is there any way i can do it directly as a var, without having to use an obj?

Comment: @IgliKadija: see the other answer